# Can I move elements from a range-based for?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Suppose I have some code like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> produce(const std::string& str){
    // create a vector based on input
}

void consume(const std::string& str){
    for (auto i:produce(str))
        // do some thing that use the str
        // and I'd like to move it from the vector
        some_process(str) // for example, move into this function
}
```

I just wonder if the compiler (I may use either VS2015 or gcc 6) can optimize to move the elements into for-loop. Or what should I do to make it move in, since the string can be quite lengthy.

Would an old begin to end for loop or a coroutine help?

Comment: @songyuanyao, Won't that just bind a forwarding reference to the value returned by iterator's `operator*`? And since the iterator returns an lvalue reference to `std::string`, `std::string& &&` will collapse down to `std::string&`. [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14efce4c332a8b9f)

Comment: @Alejandro I think you're right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to move elements from that vector to `some_function()` just do `move` explicitly:

```
void some_function( std::string str );
void some_function( std::string &&str ); // or explicitly


for(auto &i:produce(str))
    some_function( std::move(i) );
```

otherwise it is not clear what you mean by moving elements into for loop.

Comment: This is fine [because](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) "If range_expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop".

Answer (score 1):

Just `auto&` with explicit `std::move` is enough.

But to be fancy

```
struct empty_t{}; 
template<class It,class B=empty_t>struct range_t:B{
  It b,e;
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
  range_t(It s,It f):b(std::move(s)),e(std::move(f)){}
  // fancy
  template<class S, class F>
  range_t(B base, S s, F f):B(std::move(base)),b(s(*this)),e(f(*this)){}
};
template<class It>range_t<It> range(It b, It e){return{std::move(b),std::move(e)};}
template<class B, class S, class F>
auto range( B base, S s, F f ){
  auto It=std::result_of_t<s(base)>;
  return range_t<It,B>{
    std::move(base),std::move(s),std::move(f)
  };
}
template<class R>
auto move_from(R& r){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return range( std::make_move_iterator(begin(r)), std::make_move_iterator(end(r)) ); 
}
template<class R>
auto move_from(R&& r){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return range(
    std::move(r),
    [](auto&r){return std::make_move_iterator(begin(r));},
    [](auto&r){return std::make_move_iterator(end(r));}
  ); 
}
```

Now, barring typos,

```
for(auto i:move_from(produce(str)))
  some_function( std::move(i) );
```

Will have `i` being a moved-from copy of each element.

But that is insane.

This technique may be useful when you have iterating ranfe/container based code that you want to be move-agnostic.

```
template<class R, class F>
auto transform_to_vector( R&& r, F&& f ){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  using rT=std::decay_t<std::result_of_t< f(*begin(std::forward<R>(r))) >>;
  std::vector<rT> retval;
  for(auto&& e:std::forward<R>(r)){
    retval.push_back( f(decltype(e)(e)) );
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Now, calling the above with `move_from(x)` as your "range" is different than calling it with `x`.  You could imagine other algorithms written like this as well.

Comment: _But that is insane_ - this time I must agree: even if I like it, it doesn't make much sense for the OP. :-)